# relation "sendmessage_messages_message_id_seq" does not exist postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, relational-database

I am trying to create a function but it prompts me error. here is my structure

```
CREATE TABLE "SendMessage_messages"
(
  message_id serial NOT NULL,
  message_subject character varying(255),
  message_content text NOT NULL,
  message_type character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  message_category character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  created_on timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  created_by character varying(255),
  updated_on timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  updated_by character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT "SendMessage_messages_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (message_id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE "SendMessage_messages"
  OWNER TO gljsxdlvpgfvui;
```

and here is the sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "SendMessage_messages_message_id_seq"
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1
  CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE "SendMessage_messages_message_id_seq"
  OWNER TO gljsxdlvpgfvui;
```

here is the function i created

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_save_message2(IN msg_sub character varying, IN msg_cont text, IN msg_type character varying, IN msg_category character varying, IN msg_created_by character varying, IN msg_updated_by character varying) RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$ DECLARE msg_id integer := 0;
BEGIN
INSERT INTO "SendMessage_messages"(
             message_subject, message_content, message_type, message_category, 
            created_on, created_by, updated_on, updated_by)
    VALUES  (msg_sub, msg_cont, msg_type, msg_category, LOCALTIMESTAMP, 
       msg_created_by, LOCALTIMESTAMP, msg_updated_by); 
       Select into msg_id currval('SendMessage_messages_message_id_seq');
  return msg_id;
END;$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.fn_save_message2(IN character varying, IN text, IN character varying, IN character varying, IN character varying, IN character varying)
  OWNER TO gljsxdlvpgfvui;
```

when i run this query

```
SELECT fn_save_message2('Test','fjaksdjflksadjflas','email','news','taqi.official@gmail.com','taqi.official@gmail.com');
```

it says this;

```
ERROR:  relation "sendmessage_messages_message_id_seq" does not exist
LINE 1: Select             currval('SendMessage_messages_message_id_...
                                   ^
QUERY:  Select             currval('SendMessage_messages_message_id_seq')
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function fn_save_message2(character varying,text,character varying,character varying,character varying,character varying) line 8 at SQL statement
********** Error **********

ERROR: relation "sendmessage_messages_message_id_seq" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01
Context: PL/pgSQL function fn_save_message2(character varying,text,character varying,character varying,character varying,character varying) line 8 at SQL statement
```

I simply insert the data it inserts into it and when i run **select message_id from table**, it also prompts the same kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

This case is well [documented](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html): `currval()` expects `regclass` as its parameter, not `text` (string). Identifier escaping within `regclass` needs to be done exactly like everywhere else (f.ex. `regclass` also supports qualifying the schema):

```
select into msg_id currval('"SendMessage_messages_message_id_seq"');
-- or:
select into msg_id currval('"myschema"."SendMessage_messages_message_id_seq"');
```

More info about [quoting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS):

> Quoting an identifier also makes it case-sensitive, whereas unquoted names are always folded to lower case. For example, the identifiers FOO, foo, and "foo" are considered the same by PostgreSQL, but "Foo" and "FOO" are different from these three and each other. (The folding of unquoted names to lower case in PostgreSQL is incompatible with the SQL standard, which says that unquoted names should be folded to upper case. Thus, foo should be equivalent to "FOO" not "foo" according to the standard. If you want to write portable applications **you are advised to always quote a particular name or never quote it**.)